# Use git in a docker bitnami image that runs in docker swarm

Tags: git, docker, bitmap, docker-swarm

I am running a standard magento image using portainer.io, the problem is that the standard image doesn't have git installed by default, i attempted to add the bitnami git image to the docker-compose.yml, the stack run successfully but i cannot access git in the command line

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'
services:
  git:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/git:2
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: none
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_magento
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_magento
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
  magento:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/magento:2
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    environment:
      - MAGENTO_HOST=localhost
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_USER=bn_magento
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_magento
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_NUMBER=9200
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - 'magento_data:/bitnami/magento'
      - 'magento_certs:/certs'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - elasticsearch
      - git
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/elasticsearch:7
    volumes:
      - 'elasticsearch_data:/bitnami/elasticsearch/data'
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  magento_data:
    driver: local
  elasticsearch_data:
    driver: local
  magento_certs:
    driver: local
```

Comment: you're attempting to use git in a different container? Why don't you install git in the container you need it? May you explain better what are you trying to do?

Comment: i have a magento module that i am working on in a git repository and i what to clone it bitnami/docker image, but this image doesn't have git installed, if i install git manually in bitnami/docker when i restart the image git will disappear

Comment: I suggest you to extend the bitnami/docker image by adding git, using a dockerfile. Then you can use the evolution version of that image.

Comment: Do you need git in the bitnami/magento image?

Comment: yes, so the only solution is a custom image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/magento:2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git -y
```

```
$ docker build -t magento-git .
```

And use `magento-git` in place of `bitnami/magento`

Comment: i get the following error when using this docker image ``source /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a2e37e35dd73fc218fd8ba8ac9613bcef3305f7addbaac5303f10dc0ceb6005e/merged/usr/bin/git is not directory``

Comment: it works now, i had created a volume that was overriding `/usr/bin/git` i removed that and is working now